# Trying to create Distribution certificate for app store in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode5, appstore-approval

Im trying to create distribution certificate in Xcode 5 for appstore, Im getting the following error.

"An error occurred while requesting a certificate"

Are you required to have development certificate before you request dist. cert? because I dont have development cert. too.

Comment: I don't think there's a sequencial relationship between Dev and Dist Certs, it's only the usual way to go, since you have to develop before distribute. Have you tried to generate the certificates via Member Center?

Comment: Member center only allows you to generate Dev certs.

Comment: I think it probably has to do something with rights.

Comment: Actually, you can generate Distribution Certificates via Member Center. Are you under a Dev Team with restricted permissions, or are you the account owner?

Comment: I have 2 accounts. In one im part of Dev team and other is standalone. In both I see option to generate dev cert only. I remember we used to generate Dist cert from here too. But I dont see that option anymore.

Comment: I see. That's odd. If you don't see the "Production" item, under Certificates, chances are that you don't have permission to perform this action. My advice would be to contact the account admin, so he can generate the cert for you (using a CSR file you'll provide), or give you the permission to do so.

Comment: I'm looking into this option. System should be intelligent enough to be more descriptive. :-/

Answer (score 0):

First you need a cer from the keychain by requesting a certificate from cerficate authority.

then login to your app dev center -->

create  a certificate (Either development or distribution ) by importing the CSR file that you have created,

then you need to create app id com.domainname.*

then you can create provisional profile using the certificate and appid

Comment: THanks Arun for reply. I cant find option to generate "distribution" cert. Can you share your screenshot. I think this option has been removed recently. I dont see it my account which isnt part of any team and has all the permissions.